# Is it a good idea to track the same working copy with Git and SVN?

Tags: git, svn, interop

### Situation

Our client requires tracking *only* deliverables (PDFs of slides and documentation, source code) with Subversion/SVN, but we choose Git for internal developing purposes.

### Research

With [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) there is a tool to basically handle a SVN repository as a remote with Git. However I do not see the possibility to track all content with Git and only some versions of some content using SVN.

### Question

Is it a good idea to use the two VCS on the same working copy to "develop" using Git and "release" finished deliverables to SVN? What obstacles may we encounter?

### Tests

I have experimented with tracking the same working using the two version control systems and it works fine so far. I solved the issue of the two VCS tracking each other using ignores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly it's suboptimal to have two competing system for one task. But you stated the SVN is mandatory.  And the alternative where *only* the SVN plays is way worse than the combo.

Using git (or other well-working VCS) to supplement a legacy one is common practice, we probably need to wait while the corporate dinosaurs die out along with their nonsense requirements.

Comment: As the team decided to use Git for development, the alternative would be to have the two VCS handling their working copies in two directories and releasing via copy&paste. Manual interaction with the filesystem would be a third system in contrast to the two VCS communicating via a common working copy, so the latter seems to be the simpler solution.